# Modelling two different relationships between the same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations

Two models Organization and User have a 1:many relationship, where an organization has multiple users (members; a user can also *not* be associated to any organization):

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  validates_associated :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization, inverse_of: :users
end
```

Everything worked, all sorts of tests pass.
Now I added an additional relationship for a moderator function, where users can have moderator rights for (multiple) organizations. Hence, a many:many relationship through a third model, which I named Moderator:

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  has_many :moderators, class_name: "Moderator", foreign_key: "reviewee_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :moderators, source: :reviewer
  validates_associated :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization, inverse_of: :users
  has_many :moderators, class_name:  "Moderator",   foreign_key: "reviewer_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :organizations, through: :moderators, source: :reviewee
end

class Moderator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reviewee, class_name: "Organization"
  belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: "User"
end
```

I intentionally used the `reviewer` and `reviewee` names. If I would just use `user_id` and `organization_id` in the Moderator model, I though this could mess things up. Because if you would then refer to `@user.organization` then it wouldn't be defined which relationship to use. Would it use the 1:many relationship between user and organization, or the many:many through relationship...? By using different names for the many:many through relationship, `@user.organization` should refer to the 1:many relationship, while `@user.reviewee` for example should refer to the many:many through relationship.

Nevertheless, after this implementation, suddenly all sorts of tests fail. For example: I have a form that signs up an additional user for an organization. Clicing a button passes the organization_id to the form for which an additional user is to be created. Now suddenly this id doesn't get passed on to the form and I get all `nil` error because the organization isn't defined (even though the link still is e.g. `url/member?organization_id=43`). And I could give many more examples.

So there seems to be some kind of conflict because of the new relationship. Perhaps it fails to understand when to use the many:many through relationship and when the 1:many relationship, even though I used the differend reviewer and reviewee names... *Have I modelled it incorrectly or is it impossible to have two different relationships between 2 of the same models?*

If I remove the second `has_many :users` line from the Organization model all tests pass again. So the problem seems to be that I have this relationship twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good and common pattern for dealing with this is called resource scoped roles.

A User can have many roles (father, mother, moderator, hula-dancer etc) in some cases the Role is scoped to a particular resource. Like father/mother is scoped to a User (the child) or a moderator can be scoped to a Forum.

Having "system-level" roles like `super-admin` which are not scoped to a resource is also common.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles
  scope :moderators, ->{ joins(:roles).where( roles: { name: 'moderator' } ) }
  belongs_to :organization
end

# columns: name:string, resource_id:int, resource_type:string, user_id:int
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :resource, polymorphic: true
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :roles, as: :resource
  has_many :users
  # This is just a relationship to users with a scope
  has_many :moderators, -> { moderators }, class_name: 'User'
end
```

So to add a moderator we would do:

```
organization = Organization.find(1)
organization.roles.create(user: organization.users.find(1), name: 'moderator')
```

To get all moderators for a organization:

```
moderators = Organization.find(1).moderators
```

The awesome thing here is that we can use our Role class on any resource - not just an organization. Even better is that there are great gems to provide this functionality such as [Rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify).

Comment: Thanks maxcal. Is there also an alternative to roles / adding a gem? I don't really like to add another gem to my app and am hoping there is a less far-reaching solution than adding roles (perhaps do this at a later stage). Perhaps use a has_and_belongs_to_many association for the moderator rights, or is that likely to produce similar problems as the ones right now?

Comment: Well is it worth it? Adding roles is about as complicated as your above solution and will give you a good way to tie in authorization. Don't be afraid of using gems - of course technical debt can be a problem but writing everything from scratch means you spend all your time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I really don't like how you have a Moderator model too, maybe its just that i'm used to using role based systems but doing `organization.moderators.first` should give me a user instead of me having to know how the system is constructed and having to do `organization.moderators.first.user`.

Comment: If I would add the roles, would I be able to keep the existing 1:many relationship between organization and user, or would I have to adjust that and convert that to a roles based relationship as well?

Comment: No that relation would remain the same

Comment: Thanks max, I'll try to implement it. In the Rolify documentation they speak of adding `resourcify` to the models to which the roles will apply. Is this the same as your two lines `has_many :roles, as: :resource` and `has_many :moderators, -> { moderators }, class_name: 'User'` ? That is, could I write `resourcify` instead of these two lines (which I don't really understand)?

Comment: Resourcify adds something like `has_many :roles, as: :resource`